# Unable to run .py files from Powershell or VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm learning python and use `VS Code` as the editor and when I try to run the `.py` file I get the following message ,

> Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: Have you added python to environment variable `PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**3 Ways to solve this :-**

1. If Python is not installed,then install it from python.org
2. If its already installed then it might not have been added to path.
   To add python to path, search for environment variables in search bar, then edit the path option and add the python installation directory location there.
3. OR you may just re-install python from python installer and tick the "add python to path" option

> Plus I would not recommend using windows store version of python. Just use normal python installer from python.org

Comment: after trying above and running `py filename.py` helped me